# Find and Replace All But Text Between Double Quotes in VS2010

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, replace

Using Quick Replace in Visual Studio 2010, how can I replace all but text surrounded by double quotes.  I am not sure if I could use WildCards or Regex to do this.  An example is below.

Here is the original code:

```
TypeByName("bPhone3", "9999");
TypeById("bFirstName", "Don");
```

and I am wanting to replace the text with something like this:

```
Type("bPhone3", "9999", Selector.Name);
Type("bFirstName", "Don", Selector.Id);
```

I am doing this for several hundred changes, so Quick Replace is my only real choice right now.  I need to find a way to keep anything in quotes and change the text around it.

Comment: Is the non-quoted text always the same?

Comment: Yes.  The only thing that changes is the quoted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was tinkering with Visual Studio's find and replace options and this is actually possible using RegEx and tagged expressions.  I used this and it works for the strings you listed.

> Find What: `TypeBy{(.*)}\({"[^"]*"}, {"[^"]*"}\);`
>
> Replace with: `Type(\2, \3, Selector.\1);`

Remember to tag 'use regular expressions' and you should be golden

More information on tagged expressions can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/12/replace-in-files-tagged-expressions-vstipfind0016.aspx)

Edit: updated a bit as I noticed you have both name and ID, may need to make a few other changes depending on other small quirks in what you want to change.

Comment: @ebyrob Yeah it took me a few tries to get it right, that's actually something I have never used before in VS, very cool feature (although a bit niche).

Comment: I always tried it without the curly braces which I think is why I was having so much trouble in the past.  (I usually shell out to vim for this stuff instead of staying in the IDE)

Comment: +1. When building search/replace expressions it helps sometimes to use helper "triangle" button next to search/replace fields - it give you basic expressions with explanations without need to search for syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with regular expressions in Visual Studio find and replace:

Find: `TypeByName\((\".+?\"),\ (\".+?\")\);`

Replace: `Type($1, $2, Selector.Name);`

Which would turn 
`TypeByName("bPhone3", "9999");` into 
`Type("bPhone3", "9999", Selector.Name);`

**Edit** 
you can also do this:

Find: `TypeBy(.+)\((\".+?\"),\ (\".+?\")\);` 
Replace: `Type($2, $3, Selector.$1);`

Which would turn 
`TypeByName("bPhone3", "9999");` into 
`Type("bPhone3", "9999", Selector.Name);`
**AND** 
`TypeById("bFirstName", "Don");` into 
`Type("bFirstName", "Don", Selector.Id);`

It basically turns `TypeBy{1}({2}, {3})` into `Type({2}, {3}, Selector.{1})`

**NOTE THAT I TESTED THIS IN VS2012, AND IT COULD BE DIFFERENT FOR VS2010**

Comment: I tried the second in VS2010 and it didn't seem to work.  Thanks for such a thorough answer though!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're looking for a refactoring engine where you can right click on a symbol, and then go to `refactor` and then `rename`

for your particular solution, you can also start with refactoring, and then toying around with default parameters

```
public void Type(string str1, string str2, string str3 = "Default String")
{ 
    ...
```

Comment: I am wanting to do this via Find and Replace, not through code.

Comment: I considered refactoring, but this is due to multiple methods being removed and consolidated into 1 method with a 3rd parameter added to specify what 'Selector' to look for.

Comment: @Andrew  I've just trimmed my post down to only reflect that

Comment: @Andrew you can also do multiple find/replace iterations instead of just 1